# Crystal Report Default Picture not changing to my Path Picture

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

Why is it the Old picture in my crystal report is not changing to my Path Image?

What wrong with my steps?

- Insert Picture Box and Select Any image.
- Format Object
- Select Picture Tab control
- Modify Graphic Location
- In Formula Workshop i've drag the fields contains my Path Image
- Then Save.

[image]

Still not working. Is there something wrong?
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found an answer to my question.

All my steps are correct but the error is in the vb.net [Picturebox].

before I will click the print button to print my report, In the form there is a picture box that display the image of the path that I will be using in the crystal report. So when the crystal report loads. The default image is showed not the image from path it because picture box is still using the image; that's why Crystal Reports cannot open the image.

Hope this is the correct reasons to my problem.

For users wondering why the image in their Crystal Reports load some time and some time not. It is because maybe you open the form that contains that image. For example you have a form company profile and there is a image of company there. Then you have some reports that will be using the company image just for the header part; then your problem is the image load correctly but some time is not. Try to dispose the image in the company form when you close the form so that the crystal report can use the image.

```
picturebox1.image.dispose()
```